# Getting the size of an array from argv[1] and filling it with random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, arguments

I need to creates an array of SIZE integers, fill the array with random numbers, then display the unsorted and sorted array contents. Here's what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int rand(void) ;

int printArray(int array[], int size)
{
    return 0 ;
}

int sortArray(int array[], int size)
{
    return 0 ;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size = atoi(argv[1]) ;
    int* array = new int [size] ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        int array[i] = rand() % 100 ;
    }

    //printArray(argv[1], size) ;
    //sortArray(argv[1], size) ;

    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
||In function 'int main(int, char**)':|
|26|error: variable-sized object 'array' may not be initialized|
|26|warning: unused variable 'array'|
|22|warning: unused variable 'array'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 2 warnings ===|
```

I assume it's because the array has to be filled at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int array[i] = rand() % 100 ;
```

Remove `int` from this line. The compiler thinks you are (re)declaring an array of size i which happens to be variable. It should be

```
array[i] = rand() % 100 ;
```

Since you are not doing anything with the declared array in the loop, you get an `unused variable` warning.